# Read multiple csv starting from different rows

Tags: python

I am trying to read multiple csv files from one directory. Files start with summaries before the actual raw data. Raw data start where the word ‘max’ is found, and it can be in any row. I have the code below, but it is giving me the following error: IndexError: list index out of range
Can anyone help me resolving this?

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(open(file_path, 'rU'),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
max_found = False
max_row = None
for index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):

    if row[index]=='max’:
       print(row)
       max_row = index
       max_found = True
       print(max_found)
       df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

I have tried the following modified codes, but program wont stop running. I am probably doing something wrong.

```
        n = 0
        with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(fp)
            while True:
                for line in csv_reader:
                    if line == "max":
                        break
                        print(line)
                        n = n + 1
                        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=n)
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52901627/edit) to include full error traceback.

Comment: With `enumerate`, index is a a simple counter, in this case the row number.  It does not make any sense to use it to index `row`.  I'd suggest putting a `print(index, row)` before the `if` so you have clearer idea of what those values are, before you try to use them.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I have tried you solution but the program does not stop running.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `pd.read_csv()` to read your data eventually, I would suggest to do this:

```
n = 0
with open(file_path) as fp:
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if line.startswith("max"):
            break
        n = n + 1
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=n)
```

The above will include the line with "max" in the CSV to read, if you mean the CSV starts with the line below the line with "max", put the line `n = n+1` to before the if statement. Also, here I assumed the line begin with "max" must exists in the file.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I have tried you solution but the program does not stop running.

Comment: I have tried the following modified code without success. The program wont stop running.